# How to access Git Bash via command prompt?

Tags: windows, ssh, git-bash

I prefer using the bash terminal to do work, on a Windows system, I would install Git bash to do work.

Recently I have the need to access a windows machine remotely, via SSH. But I find that once I SSH into the windows system I enter into the command prompt. I have tried to activate Git Bash by using:

```
> "C:\Program Files\Git\git-bash.exe"
```

But to no avail. How do I access Git-bash via ssh?

Comment: Is there any error when you run this command? You can also check if the file exist on the server at this location.

Comment: There is no error, there is no printed output. The file does exist, I typed the command by `tab` auto-complete, and O used `dir` to check as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the command I should run is

```
> "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\sh.exe"
```